# What is Cons()?

Tags: rust

The Rust tutorial example of a linked list is:

```
enum List {
    Cons(u32, Box<List>),
    Nil
}
```

What exactly is the `Cons()` struct? (It is a struct right?) I can't find any documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: `Cons` is a variant of the `List` enum. It's saying there are two possible cases of a linked list - an empty list or a head consisting of a `u32` and a `~List`

Comment: I understand the `enum` works somewhat like a C `union` and I understand how `~List` points to the next element in the list like your textbook single linked list. What I don't see is what exactly `Cons()` *is* or does. The documentation just spits it out there out of nowhere as if it were already defined or explained previously in the documentation. Is it just some sort of anonymous struct? "Tuple structs" have to be defined ahead of time: `struct Cons(u32, ~List)` and tuples don't have names: `(u32, ~List)`

Comment: That _is_ the definition of `Cons`, it's similar to the `Circle` and `Rectangle` cases of the `Shape` enum given previously in the tutorial. As it explains, variants do not have to be simple values and `Cons` looks similar to a tuple struct, although its type will be the enclosing enum type (`List` in this case).

Comment: Ah, I see! That'll teach me to mix and match tutorials I suppose... Post the answer and I'll tick it for you

Comment: @J V, in functional parlance, this is often called sum type, since what "List" can hold here is either Cons or Nil, or the sum of all its variants.

Comment: @Lee Could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Why the word `Cons` though? The name itself does not describe much. A `List` can be understood by its name, so can an `Enum`. What is a "Cons" ? Its hard to understand a datatype when the name makes no sense. [UPDATE] - accepted answer below answers this ;-).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`Cons` does not have a special meaning in Rust. It is only the name that the author of the tutorial chose to call that variant of the enum. The same `List` could have been defined as:

```
enum List {
    Pair(u32, Box<List>),
    Nil
}
```

The name `cons` comes from the Lisp family of programming languages where pairs (nodes of linked lists) are used as the fundamental building blocks of data structures. Here is one way to create the 1,2,3 list in Common Lisp:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))
```

`cons` is a shorthand of `construct` by which Lisp programmers mean *to allocate memory*. Programs that allocate lots of memory are said to be `cons`ing too much.

#### Sources

- [cons - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)
- [Marijn Haverbeke's presentation on JS performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjo5IjJyORI&t=21m40s)

Comment: `Cons` is also a useful lesson in creating self documenting code. No one needs to cram the history of a nonsensical word in their head to understand it! https://thoughtbot.com/blog/letting-your-code-speak-for-itself